# Task 'bintrayUpload' not found in root project 'bin'

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, bintray

I Followed Every step needed to publish my AAR file to JCenter and then synchronize it with Maven Central using https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish.
I wrote this command to follow his step 13 and step 14 and got this error:

G:\Android Development Application\android-studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1\bin>gradle bintrayUpload

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'bintrayUpload' not found in root project 'bin'.

**build.gradle(Project: xxxx)**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
    classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error may be occurring due to absence of JDK and JRE "bin" path in the System Environment Variables.

Just add path of the JDK AND JRE "bin" folder in Environment Variables and you are good to go.

**To add path follow steps :**

Step 1 : Right Click,On My Computer/This PC(Windows 8.1).

Step 2 : Click on Properties.

Step 3 : Click on Advanced System Settings in Left Menu and a dialog will open.

Step 4 : Dialog with Advanced Tab, move towards end of dialog and click on "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES" button.

Step 5 : In System Variables, Add Path of JDK and JRE in variable **path / PATH**.

```
Example of JDK and JRE path : 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin

C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin
```