# Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:bintrayUpload' when trying to upload an Android Library to jCenter

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I am trying to upload my library to jCenter. I am following this tutorial:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

After following the steps and getting to typing in the Android terminal "> gradlew bintrayUpload" I get the following error:

:app:bintrayUpload FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:bintrayUpload'.

  > No value has been specified for property 'packageName'.
  >   No value has been specified for property 'user'.
  >   No value has been specified for property 'apiKey'.
  >   No value has been specified for property 'repoName'.

Before flagging my question as a duplicate, I shall indicate that i tried the solutions from the following stackoverflow questions:

[Publications(s) specified but no publications exist in project :library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917349/publicationss-specified-but-no-publications-exist-in-project-library)

After trying that solution, I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'bintrayUpload' not found in root project 'UniFont'.

Searching this error, I got to the following solution from this question on stackoverflow:
[Task 'bintrayUpload' not found in root project 'bin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715851/task-bintrayupload-not-found-in-root-project-bin)

That was not the solution for me. My path with jdk/jre exists. I have tried switching between them multiple times. Optional question:

**Do I need to declare both JDK and JRE paths into Windows Envirorment Variables?**

Here is my top level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {

//apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle(app module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'Library Name'

publishedGroupId = '...'
libraryName = '...'
artifact = '...'

libraryDescription = 'A simple library for setting a single font in a View in Android.'

siteUrl = '...'
gitUrl = '...'

libraryVersion = '1.0'

developerId = '...'
developerName = '...'
developerEmail = '...'

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks you!

Comment: Did you declare your apiKey in `local.properties`?

Comment: Yes. I have declared my apiKey.

Comment: https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/gradle-jcenter-publish

I used this now. It says "cannot resolve symbol: pom". I had a problem with another tutorial with this. Did you have the same problem?

Comment: Thanks! But i still have the same problem: "Cannot resolve symbol: pom". Can you upload your build.gradle file and the versions of gradle that you use? It will help me a lot.

Comment: Ok i added. hope to be helpful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple tutorial for uploading your libraries to bintray.

Your `build.gradle` file of project should be something like this.

```
buildscript {
 //...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        }
}
    //...    
}
```

And add these lines at the end of `build.gradle` file of your desired module which you want to upload to jcenter

```
ext {
    developerId = 'your username in bintray'
    developerName = 'your name'
    developerEmail = 'your email'
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'your library name in bintray'

    publishedGroupId = 'your group id'
    libraryName = 'your library name(better to be as like as bintrayName)'

    artifact = 'your artifact'

    libraryDescription = 'description'
    libraryVersion = 'version'

}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smasoumi/Bintray/master/install.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smasoumi/Bintray/master/bintray.gradle'
```

And also add your apiKey and username of bintray to your `local.properties` and change your gradle version to `2.2.1`

Then execute

```
gradlew.bat install
```

If it shows successful message then upload your project to bintray by this command

```
gradlew.bat bintrayUpload
```

Also be sure that JDK path is set.

Comment: This was not really the solution. I don't know how, but I made it work. But anyway, I am giving you the accepet and a vote up for your interest and help.

Comment: what is the role of the following line? Can we skip this line?                                                                             
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smasoumi/Bintray/master/install.gradle'

Comment: @VladIancu You should not give free upvotes. The answer doesn't help. Should not have been accepted. It confuses other people.